# Tidyeval in a function with dplyr and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

So I create the name with `:=`, but I want to use it in ggplot2 as `y` which does not seem to work.

```r
library(tidyverse)
date_group_plot_line <- function(df, group_col, summarise_col) {
  group_col  <-enquo(group_col)
  summarise_col <- enquo(summarise_col)

  name <- paste0(rlang::quo_name(summarise_col), "_", "mean")

  df %>%
    dplyr::group_by(!!group_col) %>%
    dplyr::summarise( !!name := mean(!!summarise_col)) %>%
    dplyr::filter(!is.na(!!group_col)) %>%
    ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x=!!group_col, y= !!name )) +
    ggplot2::geom_point()
}

date_group_plot_line(diamonds, cut, price)
#> Warning: package 'bindrcpp' was built under R version 3.4.4
```

[image]

Created on 2019-05-08 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: You have passed a constant string (a name) as `y` aesthetic. Instead do `aes(y = !!sym(name))` or `aes(y = .data[[name]])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of  @LionelHenry in the comment section of the question here is my own answer:

```r
library(tidyverse)

date_group_plot_line <- function(df, group_col, summarise_col) {
  group_col  <-enquo(group_col)
  summarise_col <- enquo(summarise_col)

  name <- paste0(rlang::quo_name(summarise_col), "_", "mean")

  df %>%
    dplyr::group_by(!!group_col) %>%
    dplyr::summarise( !!name := mean(!!summarise_col)) %>%
    dplyr::filter(!is.na(!!group_col)) %>%
    ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x=!!group_col, y= !!rlang::sym(name) )) +
    ggplot2::geom_point()
}

date_group_plot_line(diamonds, cut, price)
#> Warning: package 'bindrcpp' was built under R version 3.4.4
```

[image]

Created on 2019-05-08 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).